# OpenGL - Accessing bindless textures inside glMultiDrawElementsIndirect without NV_gpu_shader5

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

I am using `glMultiDrawElementsIndirect` with a combination of `ARB_bindless_texture` to draw things. I fetch texture handles with the built in vertex shader variable `gl_DrawID`. This variable is said to to be a dynamically uniform expression which means I dont have to depend on `NV_gpu_shader5` when accessing bindless textures inside the shader. It looks something like this.

```
#version 460 core

out flat int MaterialIndex;

void main()
{
    ...
    MaterialIndex = gl_DrawID;
}
```

```
#version 460 core
#extension GL_ARB_bindless_texture : require

struct Material
{
    sampler2D Albedo;
    ivec2 pad0;
};

layout(std140, binding = 1) uniform BindlessUBO
{
    Material Materials[256];
} bindlessUBO;

in flat int MaterialIndex;

void main()
{
    Material material = bindlessUBO.Materials[MaterialIndex];
    vec3 albedo = texture(material.Albedo, coords).rgb;
}
```

This works on a NVIDIA RTX 3050 Ti, supporting `NV_gpu_shader5`. The model with all of its meshes and textures gets drawn correctly in one draw call. However on a AMD RX 5700XT, not supporting the extension, the driver crashes after a few seconds. Both GPUs can render the model without any textures. So now my guess would be that `MaterialIndex` is not a dynamically uniform expression even though it gets its value from one. Does passing `MaterialIndex` from a vertex to a fragment shader make it a non d.u.e? How could I obtain the index of the drawing command within `glMultiDrawElementsIndirect` in the fragment shader as a d.u.e? Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do without `NV_gpu_shader5`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why one of your shaders targets 4.3 while the other targets 4.6? The definition of dynamically uniform with regards to multi draw commands has slightly changed between version, for 4.6 I'd consider your expression as dynamically uniform since it has the same value inside the same invocation group. Even if it would not be dynamically uniform, I wouldn't expect the shader to crash but rather return garbage.

Comment: @BDL My default is always 4.3 but I had to use 4.6 because of `gl_DrawID`. I switched to 4.6 on both. Same problem. Its actually more undefinied behaviour than just crashing. Depending on where I look & move I guess. Sometimes it freezes, othertimes the whole pc crashes. If I replace `MaterialIndex` by a constant it works.

Comment: Sounds like a driver bug on AMD.

Comment: @BDL Turns out it was a driver issue.

Comment: @derhass Indeed :).

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading from AMD driver `19.12.2` to `21.12.1` the bug disappeared. So passing `gl_DrawID` from vertex to fragment shader using the `flat` qualifier does in fact preserve it as a dynamically uniform expression and I dont need to depend on `NV_gpu_shader5` :).